# Getting error in sample core data project

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I learned about core data from : http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/, but when I developed a sample project myself, many errors come up in two files. 
Any help would be appreciated as I am a newbie in iPhone development

```
    //
//  PupilViewController.m
//  Pupils
//
//  Created by Lukasz Mozdzen on 21.04.2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Lukasz Mozdzen. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PupilViewController.h"

@interface PupilViewController ()
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *pupils;

@end

@implementation PupilViewController


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Fetch the devices from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Pupil"];
    self.pupils = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.pupils.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSManagedObject *pupil = [self.pupils objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [pupil valueForKey:@"name"], [pupil valueForKey:@"surname"]]];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[pupil valueForKey:@"telephone"]];

    return cell;
}



@end
```

Error Log :

```
/Users/Lukasz/Desktop/Pupils/Pupils/PupilViewController.m:36:5: Use of undeclared identifier 'NSFetchRequest'

/Users/Lukasz/Desktop/Pupils/Pupils/PupilViewController.m:36:21: Use of undeclared identifier 'fetchRequest'

/Users/Lukasz/Desktop/Pupils/Pupils/PupilViewController.m:36:38: Use of undeclared identifier 'NSFetchRequest'

/Users/Lukasz/Desktop/Pupils/Pupils/PupilViewController.m:37:62: Use of undeclared identifier 'fetchRequest'

/Users/Lukasz/Desktop/Pupils/Pupils/PupilViewController.m:62:5: Unknown type name 'NSManagedObject'; did you mean 'NSManagedObjectModel'?

/Users/Lukasz/Desktop/Pupils/Pupils/PupilViewController.m:63:67: Receiver type 'NSManagedObjectModel' for instance message is a forward declaration

/Users/Lukasz/Desktop/Pupils/Pupils/PupilViewController.m:64:36: Receiver type 'NSManagedObjectModel' for instance message is a forward declaration
```

Also in other file:

```
//
//  PupilDetailViewController.m
//  Pupils
//
//  Created by Lukasz Mozdzen on 21.04.2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Lukasz Mozdzen. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PupilDetailViewController.h"

@interface PupilDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation PupilDetailViewController


- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return context;
}




- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    // Create a new managed object
    NSManagedObject *newPupil = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Pupil" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newPupil setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
    [newPupil setValue:self.surnameTextField.text forKey:@"surname"];
    [newPupil setValue:self.telephoneTextField.text forKey:@"telephone"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@end
```

Error Log :

```
/Users/Lukasz/Desktop/Pupils/PupilDetailViewController.m:38:5: Unknown type name 'NSManagedObject'; did you mean 'NSManagedObjectModel'?

/Users/Lukasz/Desktop/Pupils/PupilDetailViewController.m:38:34: Use of undeclared identifier 'NSEntityDescription'; did you mean 'kSecAttrDescription'?

/Users/Lukasz/Desktop/Pupils/PupilDetailViewController.m:38:34: Bad receiver type 'CFTypeRef' (aka 'const void *')

/Users/Lukasz/Desktop/Pupils/PupilDetailViewController.m:39:6: Receiver type 'NSManagedObjectModel' for instance message is a forward declaration

/Users/Lukasz/Desktop/Pupils/PupilDetailViewController.m:40:6: Receiver type 'NSManagedObjectModel' for instance message is a forward declaration

/Users/Lukasz/Desktop/Pupils/PupilDetailViewController.m:41:6: Receiver type 'NSManagedObjectModel' for instance message is a forward declaration

/Users/Lukasz/Desktop/Pupils/PupilDetailViewController.m:45:11: Receiver type 'NSManagedObjectContext' for instance message is a forward declaration
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Did you add `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` to the relevant files (or to the precompiled header file NNN-Prefix.h) ?

Comment: No, I didn't :/ Now it's better but still got 3 errors which never seen before: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PupilDetailViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PupilViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Did you add `CoreData.framework` to your project?

Comment: Wondering how long it took for you to get this, I finally fixed it too! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add the Framework for coredata in your bundle before using the same.

As you said, you are a newbie in iPhone development, I would suggest you to refer to [apple docs on coredata](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) before implementing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It nearly solved my problem. Looks like I have to learn more and more but I prefer to do this on my mistakes. Now I've got this:
2013-04-22 10:57:26.656 Pupils[14749:c07] -[AppDelegate managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x811ebd0
2013-04-22 10:57:26.658 Pupils[14749:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x811ebd0'

Comment: *** First throw call stack:
(0x15bb012 0x13e0e7e 0x16464bd 0x15aabbc 0x15aa94e 0x13f4663 0x2b55 0x2c5a 0x408103 0x4084df 0x41b288 0x408103 0x4084df 0x409c4c 0x4087ef 0x33b2c0 0x33b245 0x33b095 0x1583afe 0x1583a3d 0x15617c2 0x1560f44 0x1560e1b 0x24077e3 0x2407668 0x324ffc 0x288d 0x27b5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Comment: The error means that you have not implemented the method - managedObjectContext in your view controller. See where you have implemented it and give the reference of that VC's instance.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to adding Core Data framework in project settings, you have to `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>` in your source code. You can do it just once for entire project by placing such `#import` into .pch file for your project, typically found in "Supporting Files" group of your project tree.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, there passed some time since then and since iOS 10, the `ManagedObjectContext` has been moved to the `PersistentContainer` inside the attribute `viewContext`. This is also why you need to change the snippet from **AppCoda** a little bit so that it will call the context#

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext{

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    // call "persistentContainer" not "managedObjectContext"
    if( [delegate performSelector:@selector(persistentContainer)] ){
        // call viewContext from persistentContainer not "managedObjectContext"
        context = [[delegate persistentContainer] viewContext];
    }

    return context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import CoreData
```

in 'AppDelegate' and in the 'respective view controllers' resolved similar issues for me. I added CoreData to an existing Project and hence this automatic importing CoreData framework was missed out.

Tested with Swift 3